# Unit tests for Javacc

Tags: java, unit-testing, javacc

I'm using Javacc parser generator in my application and would like to do some unit testing on my grammar.

I would like to know if there are any Unit Test frameworks for javacc, like gUnit is for ANTLR. if not then what is the best way to test this grammar?

Comment: This question looks like it might be a better fit for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's not a framework, but there are some examples of tests for both JavaCC and JJTree grammars in [my book's example code](http://generatingparserswithjavacc.com/).

---

Tom Copeland is the author of the classic [Generating Parsers with JavaCC](http://generatingparserswithjavacc.com/). The [example code](http://generatingparserswithjavacc.com/gpwj_examples_second_edition.zip) which is referred to is available for free.

Below is a sample test case for a simple Robot grammar:

```
public class RobotTest {

    @Test
    public void tokenizeMoveCommand() {
        String cmd = "STEP 10";
        SimpleCharStream cs = new SimpleCharStream(new StringReader(cmd));
        RobotTokenManager ltm = new RobotTokenManager(cs);
        Token t = ltm.getNextToken();
        assertEquals(RobotConstants.STEP, t.kind);
        t = ltm.getNextToken();
        assertEquals(RobotConstants.NUM, t.kind);
    }

    @Test(expected = TokenMgrError.class)
    public void tokenizeFailure() {
        String cmd = "STOP 10";
        SimpleCharStream cs = new SimpleCharStream(new StringReader(cmd));
        RobotTokenManager ltm = new RobotTokenManager(cs);
        ltm.getNextToken();
    }
}
```

The grammar itself:

```
options {
    BUILD_PARSER=false;
    STATIC=false;
}
PARSER_BEGIN(Robot)

public class Robot {}
PARSER_END(Robot)
TOKEN_MGR_DECLS: {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    java.io.Reader r = new java.io.FileReader(args[0]);
    SimpleCharStream scs = new SimpleCharStream(r);
    RobotTokenManager mgr = new RobotTokenManager(scs);
    for (Token t = mgr.getNextToken(); t.kind != EOF;
      t = mgr.getNextToken()) {
        System.out.println("Found a " + RobotConstants.tokenImage[t.kind] + ": " + t.image);
    }
  }
}    
SKIP :
{
    " "
|   "\n"
|   "\r"
|   "\r\n"
}
TOKEN :
{
    <STEP   :   "STEP">
|   <RIGHT  :   "RIGHT">
|   <LEFT   :   "LEFT">
|   <NUM    :   (["1"-"9"])+ (["0"-"9"])*>
}
```

Comment: Per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion)  `"Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons."`  While your self-promotion is on topic, "if you buy my book you'll find the answer" isn't exactly helpful.

Comment: Yup, but the sample code is available for free at that link... no need to buy the book... they can just download the examples and look at the ones in the "test" chapter directory.

Comment: Good to know.  But, be warned, you caught some spam flags; get five and this gets deleted and you lose 100 rep.

Comment: @tomcopeland I hope you don't mind my edits to make your answer fully comply with SO guidelines. Please feel free to revert if I did too much. And thank you for your great work.

Comment: @lexicore: Excellent edit and very good of you, that's how the answer should have looked in the first place.

Comment: Covered [in an meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277099).

Comment: FYI to future readers: Link is dead by now